# Monitor open sde connection

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase

How can I monitor the open ArcSDE database connections without `sdemon`? I need to see at any time how many sessions are consumed from my app and if they are related to ArcGIS. I use Oracle 10.2.

Comment: Would you prefer 'the sdeamon' to be "the ArcSDE application server daemon" or "sdemon" (SDE-MONitor)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esri deprecated use of the ArcSDE application server (`giomgr` and `gsrvr` processes) in favor of exclusive Direct Connect connections at 10.2 (there are no 10.3 application server binaries).  ArcGIS 10.1 and 10.2 added a number of tools to replace the deprecated tools like `sdemon`, and 10.3 added more.  The [Do This, Not That! – Alternatives to using SDE command line tools](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2013/10/04/do-this-not-that-alternatives-to-using-sde-command-line-tools/) blog post presents a number of options for using Desktop and/or Python to perform tasks which previously involved command-line tools, including [this capability](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/002n/002n000000tm000000.htm) for Desktop and the [ListUsers](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//03q300000084000000) arcpy request, both introduced at ArcGIS 10.1.